# Rate limit exceeded

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I ran my code that get some tweets with number = 50000 tweets but after getting some of them i got this error . I reviewed the below links in the error message but couldn't get anything help

```
[WARNING] 
429:Returned in API v1.1 when a request cannot be served due to the application's rate limit having been exhausted for the resource. See Rate Limiting in API v1.1.(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)
message - Rate limit exceeded
code - 88

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d35baff5 or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=12c94134
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d35baff5-12c94134], statusCode=429, 
message=Rate limit exceeded, code=88, retryAfter=-1, 
rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=0, limit=180, 
resetTimeInSeconds=1497756414, secondsUntilReset=148}, version=3.0.3}
at 
twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
```

part 2 of error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-
plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli)    An exception occured while executing the Java class. 429:Returned in 
API v1.1 when a request cannot be served due to the application's rate 
limit having been exhausted for the resource. See Rate Limiting in API 
v1.1.(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)
[ERROR] message - Rate limit exceeded
```

I found some similar posts without solutions except one that i didn't get it well and i'm not able to write a comment due to my reputation !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter4j - Rate limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999779/twitter4j-rate-limit-exceeded)

Comment: I haven't the ability to comment due to my reputation in the link you wrote so i wrote my post , i didn't get the solution well. if you please can you help ?

Comment: You can get 900 tweets per 15 minute and it's the API limit. If you really want to load 50,000 tweets that'll take 840 minutes = 14 hours

Comment: @shiftpsh Thanks for replying and sorry for late reply . so this error means that i exceeds the limit of tweets that i should have depending on the time , Right ? but how can i control the time in coding to get more !?

Answer (score 2):

in `twitter4j` there is [`RateLimitStatus`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/RateLimitStatus.html) object. You can access this object after some api calls. For example:

```
User user = twitter.showUser(userId);
user.getRateLimitStatus();
//OR
IDs followerIDs = twitter.getFollowersIDs(user.getScreenName(), -1);
followerIDs.getRateLimitStatus();
//OR
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
result.getRateLimitStatus();
```

And maybe you can use a function to handle rate limit like this:

```
private void handleRateLimit(RateLimitStatus rateLimitStatus) {
    //throws NPE here sometimes so I guess it is because rateLimitStatus can be null and add this condition
    if (rateLimitStatus != null) {
        int remaining = rateLimitStatus.getRemaining();
        int resetTime = rateLimitStatus.getSecondsUntilReset();
        int sleep = 0;
        if (remaining == 0) {
            sleep = resetTime + 1; //adding 1 more seconds
        } else {
            sleep = (resetTime / remaining) + 1; //adding 1 more seconds
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep * 1000 > 0 ? sleep * 1000 : 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

or maybe this:

```
private void handleRateLimit(RateLimitStatus rateLimitStatus) {
    int remaining = rateLimitStatus.getRemaining();
    if (remaining == 0) {
        int resetTime = rateLimitStatus.getSecondsUntilReset() + 5;
        int sleep = (resetTime * 1000);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep > 0 ? sleep : 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Any other/better methods would also be appreciated.