# How to identify which endpoint a Twitter4j RateLimitStatusEvent contains the limit for

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am building an application in Java 8 using Twitter4J (twitter4j-core:4.0.6) to crawl friendships and followers. I am going to populate a graph structure with the data, and I am expecting to hit the rate limits pretty fast, so I am trying to build the application in such a way that only the exhausted endpoints go to sleep.

To be sure I have the correct number of remaining calls, as other apps, threads or instances also exhaust the same pool of requests, I am trying to use the RateLimitStatusListener interface to have the `onRateLimitStatus(RateLimitStatusEvent event)` and `onRateLimitReached(RateLimitStatusEvent event)` control the sleep flags for the loops.

The problem is however, that I can't seem to find anywhere to access which endpoint, i.e. "/friends/ids", "/followers/ids" or "/users/lookup", that the RateLimitStatusEvent corresponds to.

I have considered just looking up the rate limit and keep a local count, but if there are multiple instances, other apps etc. that accesses the info at the same time, the rate limits will be reached before the local count will be aware of. I might publish the application when it is finished, and then I might have more than one simultaneous user.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this with Twitter4J, or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? It may be a good starting point I guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/45199642/2183174

Comment: @kadir You are absolutely right! That is a great starting point! I was not aware that the results contained a reference to an implementation of the TwitterResult interface, which contains the returned rate limit of that particular request. I'll redesign the logic a bit and see if I get that approach working in a satisfying way.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, which is not mentioned in the comment by @kadir yet, is using `Map<String, RateLimitStatus> getRateLimitStatus(String... resources) throws TwitterException` on the `Twitter` instance.

This method will perform a REST call to the `application/rate_limit_status` endpoint and return the current rate limit status for a given `resource familiy`. Documentation of this endpoint can be found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/application/rate_limit_status).

In your case, you could use this endpoint to ask for the resource-families `friends`, `users`, `followers` and can obtain the rate-limit status of all endpoints related to this families.

However, calling this endpoint too often may also result in a rate-limit.

Comment: Also a good suggestion, but for my use case, as I explained in the question, calling that endpoint and storing it locally, which I must do to avoid rate-limiting, won't scale to concurrent users in a good way. The preferable way would be to get the info in the parameters on the delegate method `onRateLimitStatus()`, but @kadir pointed me towards a possibility which, with some redesign of the control flow and logic, can give much of the same  as the delegate method.